# Dual counts on query results in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm working on a query that returns a user's name, id and the amount of actions and comments belonging to the user. Here is the query in SQL:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, (
    SELECT count(*) from actions where users.id = actions.user_id
  ) as Action_Count, (
    SELECT count(*) from comments where users.id = comments.user_id
  ) as Comment_Count
FROM users
```

I'm somewhat new to Sequelize, but after too many hours of searching and numerous attempts, I cannot seem to figure out how to write it properly. So I hope someone here can help guide me. This has been my best attempt:

```
 User.findAll({
  attributes: ['name','id',
    [Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('actions.user_id')), 'count_of_actions'],
    [Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('comments.user_id')), 'count_of_comments']
  ],
  include: [{ attributes: [], model: Action },{ attributes: [], model: Comment }],
  group: ['user.id'],
  order: [['createdAt', 'ASC']]
})
```

But this returns the same number for `Action_Count` and `Comment_Count` (the two multiplied together) if there are any comments.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I used the `sequelize.query` to run the above sql query, which works. I'm still curious how one would do this using sequelize syntax, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue today. Here's my answer to the problem by adding distinct function:

```js
 User.findAll({
  attributes: ['name','id',
    [Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('actions.user_id'))), 'count_of_actions'],
    [Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('comments.user_id'))), 'count_of_comments']
  ],
  include: [{ attributes: [], model: Action },{ attributes: [], model: Comment }],
  group: ['user.id'],
  order: [['createdAt', 'ASC']]
})
```

The post is old, I hope this will help someone.